# CMD error filename/directory error

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, windows-10

I used to program batch files for work but I quit since a long time, now I'm back on the job and there seemed to be a bit of a problem.
I try to edit `txt` files using CMD commands on a batch file:

e.g. `echo hello >> *.txt`

the thing is I want to add the text to all the `txt` files in that directory and I remember the * represented all the files in that directory with the same extension unless it's used as `*.*` then it includes all the files, but now all it does is just writes this error on cmd:

> The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

Can anyone can give a little help?

Comment: the directory has many other non txt fiels in it, I need to specify the extension.

Comment: is it possible to chat? or message you in private, way easier. ( I dont know how to do it on this website stil la rookie)

Comment: the code line still not working...is it not possible to just do it in a simple way? like why isnt echo >> *.txt working? it used to work few years ago

Comment: well..I changed it , I even tried using %cd% still errors

Comment: the following usage of the path operator in batch-parameter substitution is invalid: %~FPNXF

Comment: I just added as an answer so look it over when you get a chance too for more clarification than the comments.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [FOR /F](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) loop with a [DIR](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) command to iterate the full paths and pass those over to the redirection append `>>` to echo to the text files accordingly.

### Example FOR Loop

*Be sure to change the value of the `Folder=` variable to be the directory you need to append to the files with the `ECHO` command.*

**Confirmed working batch script example**

```
@ECHO ON
SET Folder=C:\MyFolder
CD /D "%Folder%"
FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%A IN ('DIR /B /A-D "%Folder%\*.txt"') DO ECHO HELLO>>%%~fA
PAUSE
EXIT
```

---

### Further Resources

- [DIR](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html)
- [FOR /F](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)

  > In addition, substitution of FOR variable references has been
  >   enhanced. You can now use the following optional syntax:
  >
  > ```
  > %~I         - expands %I removing any surrounding quotes (")
  > %~fI        - expands %I to a fully qualified path name
  > %~dI        - expands %I to a drive letter only
  > %~pI        - expands %I to a path only
  > %~nI        - expands %I to a file name only
  > %~xI        - expands %I to a file extension only
  > %~sI        - expanded path contains short names only
  > %~aI        - expands %I to file attributes of file
  > %~tI        - expands %I to date/time of file
  > %~zI        - expands %I to size of file
  > %~$PATH:I   - searches the directories listed in the PATH
  >                environment variable and expands %I to the
  >                fully qualified name of the first one found.
  >                If the environment variable name is not
  >                defined or the file is not found by the
  >                search, then this modifier expands to the
  >                empty string
  > ```

Comment: so basically FPNXA that you used is combinations of FOR /F syntaxes?

Comment: @saladassPEPE Here's how [Accepting An Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) works in case you didn't know

Comment: im running a script, and no it didnt work I was mistaken , the result shown was from other test scripts

Comment: Change `FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %A IN ('DIR /A-D /B "C:\Folder\*.txt"') DO ECHO HELLO >> "%~FPNXA"` to `FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %A IN ('DIR/B/A-D "C:\Folder\*.txt"') DO @ECHO HELLO>>"%A"` In a batch file double up the %, **`%A`** becomes **`%%A`**

Comment: If you have already turned off echoing using `@ECHO OFF` then the `@` can be omitted. The variable substitutions are shown, they should be either, `%~dpnxA` OR `%~fA` however as the full path was given the full path is already output as %A there is no need to substitute.